# Views (pages) without timeline

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a relativly simple question. What would be the best way to recreate a multiple page application without using the timeline. I created a pagemanager class that add's and removes classes, with classes acting as pages. Now this doesn't really seem like a very effective method.
I believe flex offers a similiar approach as HTML, but it's already to late to move to flex at this point.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you create an own class that works similar as the viewstack in Flex. Use it with an interface (for example IPage) to force methods that you viewstack uses to load and unload/dispose the pages. Once you run the changePage method on the viewstack, you dispose the current page and open the new page. When you have this running it is easy to add transitions.

Something like this (This code is NOT validated):

---

```
_view = new ViewStack();
_view.addPage(Pages.INTRO, new IntroPage());
_view.addPage(Pages.OUTRO, new OutroPage());
_view.changePage(Pages.INTRO);
```

---

IPage.as

```
package
{
    public interface IPage
    {
        function open() : void

        function close() : void
    }
}
```

---

ViewStack.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class ViewStack extends Sprite
    {
        public function ViewStack()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function addPage(pageID : String, page : IPage) : void
        {
            // add page to list
        }

        public function removePage(pageID : String) : void
        {
            // remove page from list
        }

        public function changePage(pageID : String) : void
        {
            if(_currentPage)
            {
                _currentPage.close();
                removeChild(_currentPage);
            }

            _currentPage = getPageById(pageID);
            _currentPage.open();
            addChild(_currentPage);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the best solution indeed. The main problem with this is that after deleting pages, all the eventlisteners in those pages are still running, and I would have to remove them manually. Still doable, but not very handy.

Also, I am not familiar with interfaces (shame), why would I place the open and close functions in the interface and not in the viewstack class, and how does it function in the interface?

Comment: By using an Interface you can have multiple pages that implements the same interface and are forced to have the defined methods/functions setup. For example: IntroPage and OutroPage have different functionality in their open/close methods. But as long as they have those methods they can be used by the viewstack without referring to the actual classes (and their references). You could also accomplish this with an abstract class (AbstractPage) where you override the mehods.